# What does に and された mean here?

Tags: grammar

This is the sentence

> 「私の兄は陛下の親衛隊長です。陛下とも懇意にしていただいておりますので、多少の事情は把握しております。無事、回復なされたようで何よりでございます、サーシャ様」
>
> 「えっ」
>
> サーシャのことを知っていたことにしてしまった。
>
> まぁ、**もし兄に確認されたとしても**、超直感を持つカインなら何とかしてくれるだろう。

My question is who is the one that got 確認? what does もし兄に確認された mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the context, 兄に確認される could be interpreted in two ways: either (1) the brother checks something, or (2) someone asks the brother to verify some information.

In this particular case, the latter seems to be the case.